# Handling multiple images in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, phasset, photosframework

I'm trying to develop an iOS app where users can pick their images from Camera Roll, Facebook, Instagram, etc. and edit them later (crop, filters, rotate).

Now, I'm having problems loading multiple images using Photos Framework to get PHAssets and converting them to full quality images and show them in next view.
When loading full quality images in SelectedImagesView I get memory warning and the app just blows because I'm storing images in memory.

How can I store a list of selected images (original and edited) and show them to the user according to the image "SelectedImagesView"?

[1) PickImagesView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Beh.png)

[2) SelectedImagesView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbfJs.jpg)

So far, this is how I get the images using the Photo Framework:

1. Load the PHAssets from selected album in CollectionView
2. When user select an image, store the PHAsset identifier in NSUserDefault
3. When user finish selecting images, load all selected identifiers and send them to next View
4. Load images from Photos Library in SelectedImagesView with following code:

   ```
   func processImages() {
       for identifier in self.selectedAssets {
           let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
           options.deliveryMode = .FastFormat

           // request images no bigger than 1/3 the screen width
           let maxDimension = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 3 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
           let size = CGSize(width: maxDimension, height: maxDimension)

           let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([identifier], options: nil)
           guard let asset = assets.firstObject as? PHAsset
               else { fatalError("no asset") }

           PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options)
           { result, info in
               // probably some of this code is unnecessary, too,
               // but I'm not sure what you're doing here so leaving it alone
               let photo: Photo = Photo()
               photo.originalPhoto = result
               self.selectedImages.append(photo)     
           }
       }
       self.tableView!.reloadData()
       self.tableView!.reloadInputViews()
   }
   ```

But the memory cost is too high.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need all the selected images in full resolution at the same time?  Why not just one by one in the second view?

Comment: Because I need to show the user all the selected images in scroll view and let them to select one image to edit it in another view

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do https://www.socialprintstudio.com/app.html

Comment: You cannot hold all the images in memory at the same time. Redesign your app to use smaller in memory representations. Your current approach cannot be "fixed" since the basic approach just consumes all device memory.

Comment: That's my question. I know there's better approaches like storing images in CoreData (not recommended), store images in Cache (I don't know how to do this), store images in TempDirectory (I don't know if this is good)